# database - date - multiple columns or one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a database, and can see that the table was set up with multiple columns (day,month,year) as opposed to one date column. 
I'm thinking I should convert that to one, but wanted to check if there's much point to it.

I'm rewriting the site, so I'm updating the code that deals with it anyway, but I'm curious if there is any advantage to having it that way?

The only thing it gets used for is to compare data, where all columns get compared, and I think that an integer comparison might be faster than a date comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consolidate them to a single column - an index on a single date will be more compact (and therefore more efficient) than the compound index on 3 ints. You'll also benefit from type safety and date-related functions provided by the DBMS.

Even if you want to query on month of year or day of month (which doesn't seem to be the case, judging by your description), there is no need to keep them separate - simply create the appropriate computed columns and intex *them*.

Comment: *"simply create the appropriate computed columns and intex them."* what?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO For example, a column that gets its value by extracting a month from the date column.

Answer (score 3):

The date column makes sense for temporal data because it is fit for purpose.

However, if you have a specific use-case where you are more often comparing month-to-month data instead of using the full date, then there is a little bit of advantage - as you mentioned - int columns are much leaner to store into index pages and faster to match.

The downsides are that with 3 separate int columns, validation of dates is pretty much a front-end affair without resorting to additional coding on the SQL Server side.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, a single date field is ideal, as it allows for more efficient comparison, validity-checks at a low level, and database-side date-math functions.

The only significant advantage of separating the components is when a day or month first search (comparison) is frequently needed. Maybe an "other events that happened on this day" sort of thing. Or a monthly budgeting application or something.

(Even then, a proper date field could probably be made to work efficiently with proper indexing.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would suggest you replace the 3 columns with a single column that contains the date in Julian which is a floating point number. The part before the dot gives the day, the part after the dot gives the time within the day. Calculations will be easy and you can also easily convert Julian back into month/day/year etc. I believe that MS Excel stores dates internally as a floating point number so you will be in good company.

Comment: [How dates are stored](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server)